# Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::isSite() in Joomla 4

Tags: plugin, joomla-4.x, debug

I updated to Joomla 4! and the site displays an error. Here is a snippet of the debug log.

```
2021-11-23T16:27:43+00:00   CRITICAL ::1    error   Uncaught Throwable of type Error thrown with message "Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::isSite()". Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\Plugin\CMSPlugin.php(285): plgContentEDSAnimate->onContentPrepare('com_content.fea...', Object(stdClass), Object(Joomla\Registry\Registry), 0)
    #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\vendor\joomla\event\src\Dispatcher.php(486): Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin->Joomla\CMS\Plugin\{closure}(Object(Joomla\Event\Event))
    #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\Application\EventAware.php(111): Joomla\Event\Dispatcher->dispatch('onContentPrepar...', Object(Joomla\Event\Event))
    #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\components\com_content\src\View\Featured\HtmlView.php(155): Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication->triggerEvent('onContentPrepar...', Array)
    #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\Cache\Controller\ViewController.php(102): Joomla\Component\Content\Site\View\Featured\HtmlView->display()
    #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\BaseController.php(683): Joomla\CMS\Cache\Controller\ViewController->get(Object(Joomla\Component\Content\Site\View\Featured\HtmlView), 'display')
    #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\components\com_content\src\Controller\DisplayController.php(125): Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->display(true, Array)
    #7 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\MVC\Controller\BaseController.php(730): Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Controller\DisplayController->display()
    #8 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher.php(146): Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute('display')
    #9 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\components\com_content\src\Dispatcher\Dispatcher.php(55): Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ComponentDispatcher->dispatch()
    #10 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\Component\ComponentHelper.php(389): Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Dispatcher\Dispatcher->dispatch()
    #11 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\Application\SiteApplication.php(206): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_content')
    #12 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\Application\SiteApplication.php(245): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->dispatch()
    #13 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php(278): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute()
    #14 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\includes\app.php(63): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
    #15 D:\xampp\htdocs\test-web\index.php(32): require_once('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
    #16 {main}
```

Additionally an error is displayed [[on the main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGtrg.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGtrg.png):

> Call to undefined method Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::isSite()

**in D:\xampp\htdocs\lz-altstadt\plugins\content\edsanimate\edsanimate.php (line 44)**

```
private $globalOffset = 0;

public function onContentPrepare($context, $article, $params, $limitstart)
{
    if (!JFactory::getApplication()->isSite())
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

The weird thing is: I would say there is a bug in the plugin CMSPlugin or edsanimate, but I can not find plugins under this name. So I absolutely do not know where this error comes from.

Comment: Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isSite is no longer a valid method in Joomla 4 according to the comments in CMSApplication.php.

```
 @deprecated  4.0 Use isClient('site') instead.
```

Comment: Yeah, I also read this so often. But I did not develop the plugins. So I won't change this. I would delete any plugin to get it to work. The question is how we find the plugin which calls this.

Comment: You need to disable the plugin called edsanimate with a Plugin Type of content.

Comment: Thanks, overlooked the plugin with this name.